# Numeric value directly after backreference

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use `re.sub` on a string with a numeric value directly after a numeric backreference. That is, if my replacement value is `15.00` and my backreference is `\1`, my replacement string would look like:

`\115.00`, which as expected will throw an `error: invalid group reference` because it thinks my backreference group is `115`.

Example:

```
import re

r = re.compile("(Value:)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)")

to_replace = "Value:0.99" # Want Value:1.00

# Won't work:
print re.sub(r, r'\11.00', to_replace)

# Will work, but don't want the space
print re.sub(r, r'\1 1.00', to_replace)
```

Is there a solution that doesn't involve more than `re.sub`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an unambiguous backreference syntax `\g<1>`. See [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) reference:

> `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group `20`, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tW3dA7/1).

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/Bfbd79):

```
import re
r = re.compile("(Value:)([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)")
to_replace = "Value:0.99" # Want Value:1.00
print(re.sub(r, r'\g<1>1.00', to_replace))
# => Value:1.00
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there must be some more precise backreference syntax, but didn't know which.

Comment: Thanks, but note that `\g<1>` syntax only works in the `repl` argument of `re.sub` as the docs say! I had to unambiguously refer to a backreference within the search-pattern itself. The solution was to use named groups: `r"(?P<x>[1-9])0\d(?P=x)0\d"` which captures the group as name "x" and then looks for a repetition of that value. The first part of my string is the capture and the second is the re-use.

Comment: @MitchMcMabers The `(?P=x)` is an *inline backreference* used in the regex pattern while this answer and question are about *replacement backreferences* used in the replacement pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, but I added my comment because this is the first Google result for how to add numbers after backreferences. Now both types of visitors will find the technique they need for their backreferences! :)

Comment: @MitchMcMabers I doubt it will help a lot of visitors, the question is marked as a dupe and there is an automatic redirect for those who are not SO users to the original question.